# Non colliding objects which has Colliding Pairs, Pymunk Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision, pymunk

I would like to implement a code which has non colliding pairs with colliding objects. My pairs are 2 balls which are connected to each other. I want those 2 pair ball to collide. However I don't want those 2 balls to collide with other pairs.

How can I implement a mask with this much of categories in pymunk ShapeFilter? Should I use bitwise operators? As you can see in my shape filter I tried to ignore values which is out of their category except their pairwise catergory, BUT it doesnt work for 4 + number of balls?

My code cannot handle those states of balls with each other.

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.color import *
import pymunk
import pymunk.pygame_util
from pymunk import Vec2d
import  sys
#import tensorflow as tf
from time import sleep
import time
import numpy as np
from math import exp
from random import seed
from random import random
import datetime
import operator


class Game:
    def __init__(self):


        # initialize game window
        pygame.init()

        self.screen_x= 1500
        self.screen_y=  200

        # Pool Hyper Parameters
        # BE CAREFULL CHANGING THESE VARIABLES

        self.pool_size = 2
        self.pool_time = 15
        #########################################################################
        # NN lists
        #Pygame fonts
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 16)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.screen_x,self.screen_y+200)) #screen display
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock() ## init clock
        self.running = True
        # pymunk init
        self.space = pymunk.Space()
        self.space.gravity = (0.0, -1200.0)  #gravity setup
        self.draw_options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(self.screen)#adds add physics to the screen


    def new(self):
        # start a new game
        ## Balls
        self.balls = []

        ## creating walls
        self.static_body = self.space.static_body
        self.static_lines = [pymunk.Segment(self.static_body, (0.0,50.0), (1500.0, 50.0), 0.0) ## road
                            ,pymunk.Segment(self.static_body, (1499.0, 150.0), (1499.0, 700.0), 0.0)
                            ,pymunk.Segment(self.static_body, (1800, 50.0), (1800, 170.0), 0.0)
                           ,pymunk.Segment(self.static_body, (0.0,50.0), (0.0, 700.0), 0.0) ## wall 1
                            ]
        ## set walls
        for line in self.static_lines:
            line.elasticity = 0.95
            line.friction = 01.5
            #line.filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(categories=np.uint8(0))

        self.space.add(self.static_lines)
        # Go to run
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        # Game Loop
        self.playing = True
        self.no_ball = True
        while self.running:
            self.events()
            if self.no_ball == True:
                self.unit(self.pool_size)

            self.update()


    def update(self):


            self.screen.fill(THECOLORS["white"])
            ### Draw stuff
            self.balls_to_remove = []
            for ball in self.balls:
                if ball.body.position.y < 0: self.balls_to_remove.append(ball)
            for ball in self.balls_to_remove:
                self.space.remove(ball, ball.body)
                self.balls.remove(ball)
            self.space.debug_draw(self.draw_options)
            ### Update physics
            self.dt = 1.0/60.0
            for k in range(1):
                self.space.step(self.dt)

            ### Flip screen
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(50)
            pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(self.clock.get_fps()))


    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_y: ## Creates a ball
                    self.running = False
                    pass

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                (self.mouse_x,  self.mouse_y) = pymunk.pygame_util.get_mouse_pos(self.screen)



    def unit (self, number_balls=None):
        #Mass And Radius units
        self.mass = 20
        self.radius = 10

        #Mass and Radius for joint
        self.mass_joint = 2
        self.radius_joint = 2

        #for n in number_balls
        self.objs = list()
        for i in range(number_balls):

            self.objs.append(pymunk.Body())
            self.objs.append(pymunk.Body())
            self.objs.append(pymunk.Body())

            #Inertia
            self.inertia = pymunk.moment_for_circle(self.mass, 0, self.radius, (0,0))
            self.inertia_joint = pymunk.moment_for_circle(self.mass_joint , 0, self.radius_joint, (0,0))  
            #Body
            self.objs[i], self.objs[i+1] = pymunk.Body(self.mass, self.inertia), pymunk.Body(self.mass, self.inertia)
            self.objs[i+2] = pymunk.Body(self.mass_joint, self.inertia_joint)

            #Position
            x = 100
            self.objs[i].position = x   , 90
            self.objs[i+1].position = x+24, 90
            self.objs[i+2].position = x+12, 90
            #Links
            self.link_1 = pymunk.PinJoint(self.objs[i], self.objs[i+2], (0, 0), (0, 0))
            self.link_2 = pymunk.PinJoint(self.objs[i+1], self.objs[i+2], (0, 0), (0, 0))
            # Adding Body links
            self.space.add(self.link_1)
            self.space.add(self.link_2)

            #First ball shape
            self.shape_first = pymunk.Circle(self.objs[i], self.radius, (0,0))
            self.shape_first.elasticity = 0.4
            self.shape_first.friction = 0.9
            self.space.add(self.objs[i], self.shape_first)

            #Fsecond ball shape
            self.shape_second = pymunk.Circle(self.objs[i+1], self.radius, (0,0))
            self.shape_second.elasticity = 0.4
            self.shape_second.friction = 0.9
            self.space.add(self.objs[i+1], self.shape_second)

            #Joint shape        
            self.shape_joint = pymunk.Circle(self.objs[i+2], self.radius_joint, (0,0))
            self.shape_joint.elasticity = 0.4
            self.shape_joint.friction = 0.9
            #self.shape_joint.sensor == True
            self.space.add(self.objs[i+2], self.shape_joint)


            body_first_category = (i*3)+1#"{0:b}".format(int(i+1)) 
            body_second_category = (i*3)+2
            body_joint_category = (i*3)+3
            print (body_first_category )
            print(body_second_category )
            print(body_joint_category )

            #"{0:b}".format(int(i+2))
            self.shape_first.filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(categories=body_first_category, mask=(body_joint_category and body_second_category)  )            
            self.shape_second.filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(categories=body_second_category, mask=(body_first_category and body_joint_category)  )
            self.shape_joint.filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(categories=body_joint_category, mask=(body_first_category and body_second_category))  

            self.balls.append(self.shape_first)
            self.balls.append(self.shape_second)
            self.balls.append(self.shape_joint)
            self.no_ball = False



g = Game()
while g.running:
    g.new()


##pg.quit()
```

Please help :)

P.S: Example Library shape filter class:

http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.ShapeFilter

Comment: Please don't post so much code on Stack Overflow. It can take a lot of time to analyze and debug it, so try to reduce it to the absolute [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cleared code could you please check my friend

Comment: I want to collide with one category and ignore all other categories. Please check my code under unit() function. My code can compile. I used XOR and NOT operands. To collide one ignore all others. However this is might not be good thing to do. I know your code from previous question it works. But this is a new problem and it is bit unique @skrx

Comment: How many of these ball pairs will be existing at the same time?

Comment: minimum 50 balls, But I believe your method can work on 32 different category because of ALLMASK 2^32. If you can help I would be soo thankfull @skrx Do you think there is another way?

Comment: If you need more than 32 categories, this approach will probably not work (or perhaps a different data type can be used?). Maybe we should take a look at [collision handlers](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.CollisionHandler). It's been a while since I used Pymunk the last time, so I'm not sure.

Comment: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.ShapeFilter I am trying to understand this logic. if I set mask to certain value will it make it collideable with that category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172988/discussion-between-skrx-and-meric-ozcan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with collision callbacks, I think begin callback is a good option for you. On each pair of shapes you want to collide you set a common identifier, and then check that in the callback, and return True only when the two objects colliding belong to the same pair.

Something like this:

```
def only_collide_same(arbiter, space, data):
    a, b = arbiter.shapes
    return a.pair_index == b.pair_index

h = space.add_collision_handler(1,1)
h.begin = only_collide_same

for i in range(10):
    # create shapes and bodies ...
    # then for each pair of shapes:
    shape1.pair_index = i
    shape1.collision_type = 1
    shape2.pair_index = i
    shape2.collision_type = 1
```

Comment: Good solution. BTW, is it possible to increase the number of ShapeFilter categories?

Comment: Yes, but it requires some changes. Chipmunk have a typedef called cpBitmask used for categories and masks. It can be overridden by defining the desired type with CP_BITMASK_TYPE at (chipmunk) compile time. And then pymunk needs to be updated so that the type of cpBitmask in _chipmunk_cffi_abi matches whatever was defined.